# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 - Changing Base64 variant to (RFC 6920)

Tags: c#, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are configuring our WSO2 environment to tie in with our C# web-services.  While making the calls to the service through the API manager we are seeing a 401 Unauthorized error.  Looking at the event log in the server that is hosting the web service we see a "Security token validation failed" error stating that the Signature validation failed.  We want to change the way the token is being encrypted in base64 so that it is unpadded (RFC 6920) so that it will work with our C# services.

Has anyone made these changes to the the base64 encoding of a WSO2 JWT token or know how we can make a change to a system configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any configuration has not provided to change the token encoding other than base64. I can suggest a workaround in which you can capture the request before it hits the backend and decode it using base64 and encoded again with your preferred encoding method and redirect it to the backend. If I elaborate the workaround further you can add an ESB in between API Manager and backend. create a proxy in ESB and point api created in API Manager to that proxy. end point of proxy should be back end. In that proxy you can add a class mediator in which you can decode the request using base64 and encode again with your encoding method and send to backend.